# How does Android 2.2 know the version number of 4.0?

Tags: android

Let's say I have a project that targets 4.0, but supports versions down to 2.2. When running the following on a 2.2 device, I get the correct value which is 14.

```
Integer version = Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH
```

To me, this seems odd, I am expecting a null value or an error since the device is using the 2.2 API and according to the 2.2 [Build.VERSION_CODES](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/os/Build.java?av=h#Build.VERSION_CODES) class, there is no mention of an `int ICE_CREAM_SANDWHICH = 14` constant. What am I missing here?

Comment: I suspect this was added with a patch/update to Android 2.2.

Comment: With what version did you compile it?

Comment: @Ahmad with 4.0 (if you are referring to the android.jar file).

Comment: Yes, try to compile  with e.g. 2.3.3 and it will return null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ahmad says, you need to compile your code with  API Level 14 in order to use the constant "ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH". The thing is that at compilation time those constants are changed into their respective values. That means that at runtime any device won't see the "ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH" constant but the value 14 (even if it is a device with Froyo 2.2 installed).

In other words, in your code:

```
Integer version = Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH;
```

in the device:

```
Integer version = 14;
```

It is not exactly like that, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I already answered that in the comments, but I suppose I can also write it down as an answer.

The value Build.VERSION_CODE will give you depends on the API Level on which you compiled the project, so if you compiled it on API Level 10 of course you will get no value returned when you call Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH, but if you compile it on API Level 14 you will get the correct value.

So if the compilation Level is lower than the build number you are trying to call,  it will return null.

Comment: I just tried it with 2.2 and I can't even compile because the value does not exist so I believe you :). But this brings up another question, I thought it didn't matter which version I compiled my project with when supporting old devices since the old devices would just run the app using their own version of android, but obviously something else is going on here, is the 2.2 device "using" some parts of the 4.0 jar file when running on old devices? It can't be using the entire file since it's about 17mb?

Comment: Yes, I suppose they don't use everthing(It would be cool tough if this would be possible, then there would be no need to make thing backwardscompatible), but I think they override Constants like the build numbers